# Networkx, changing node colors

Tags: python, colors, networkx

I want to change the color of the node, based on the attribute values. Specifically in this case, when the attribute 'status' is 1, I want the color to be something and when it's 0, some other color. One restriction is that I want the nodes to be printed in a lattice format, where I use 2d_grid_graph.

When graphing this with node_color='blue' or any other color, the output works correctly, but when I use conditionals to change the color according to 'status' it only shows one color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint
import networkx as nx

N = 10 #Lattice Size

#Random Coordinate Generator
def random(m, n):
    seen = set()

    x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)

    while True:
        seen.add((x, y))
        yield (x, y)
        x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
        while (x, y) in seen:
            x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)


#Generates Lattice
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status') 
G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes,status='1')

#Change Node attribute
num_nodes=N*N
half=int(num_nodes/2)
decaying = [0]*half
a=random(0,N-1)

for i in range(half):
    cor=next(a)
    decaying[i]=cor
for j in range(half):
    a=decaying[j]
    G.add_node(a, status='0')

node_color = []

#Plot nodes
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status') 
nx.draw(G,pos=pos,node_color=node_color, labels=labels,node_size=200)
```

Comment: Could you give some code to generate the graph?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could works:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10, 2)
color = []
for node in M:
    if node > 1:
        color.append('red')
    else:
        color.append('green')
nx.draw(M, node_color=color)
plt.show()
```

Here the application with your example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint
import networkx as nx

N = 10 #Lattice Size

#Random Coordinate Generator
def random(m, n):
    seen = set()

    x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)

    while True:
        seen.add((x, y))
        yield (x, y)
        x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
        while (x, y) in seen:
            x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)


#Generates Lattice
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status')
G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes,status='1')

#Change Node attribute
num_nodes=N*N
half=int(num_nodes/2)
decaying = [0]*half
a=random(0,N-1)

for i in range(half):
    cor=next(a)
    decaying[i]=cor
for j in range(half):
    a=decaying[j]
    G.add_node(a, status='0')

node_color = []
for status in  list(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status').values()):
    if status == '1':
        node_color.append('red')
    else:
        node_color.append('green')
#Plot nodes
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status')
nx.draw(G,pos=pos,node_color=node_color, labels=labels,node_size=200)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input!! It seems like it doesn't work for my code - gave me an error saying TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'